# ViewContoller animation from top to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I m developing a E-commerce mobile application in `iOS`. I need to know how to move from one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController` with slide animation from top to bottom.

I am using Storyboard.
App needs to works in ios6 and ios7.
Below is the code i used for tranitioning `UIViewController`

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MenuViewController *viewController = 
 (MenuViewController *)
   [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menupage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Below is the code I tried for a turn page effect and it worked fine. I need the same thing as below for a slide top to bottom

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                   forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The another method

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       MenuViewController *viewController = (MenuViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menupage"];
          MenuViewController *viewController1 = (MenuViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menupage"];

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
          viewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,480,320,480);
          [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                           animations:^{
                               viewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

                           }
                           completion:^(BOOL fin){
                               if (fin)
                               {
                                [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
                                   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:NO];
                               }
                           }];
```

Here i get animation in success manner.But i need to load same view controller twice.One is for animation and another one is for normal ViewController Load.If i didnt load second method i get some problem in nextviewController button actions.
Thanks in Advance
Sam.P

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Comment: i have tried with uiview animation

Comment: we can`t animate uiviewcontroller...we can animate uiview

Comment: i have updated my code above for curlup effect..I need for slide down effect

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
               forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
```

instead of using UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp use UIViewAnimationCoverVertical

or simply without any view animations, just change a single line.

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.I cant go with second one.But first one not work for me UiviewanimationCoverVertical is showing error

Comment: you have to do the transition using only push method. am i right?

Comment: s of course sreekanth.I need to use pushmethod alone.I have updated my another tried code above.Please check with that code and provide Good and effective solution for this.

Comment: k @sreeKanth.I can able to understand that.But my scenarion is like this.I have completely developed this application.I cant go and change every animation now with presentviewController that is the problem...For that only i go with the code above i update before half an hour.But that time for custom uiview tranistion not working

Comment: in the another method change `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.....` to `[self.view animateWithDuration:1......` try it once and let me know

Answer (score 0):

FYI @MaheThiru the push only gives u to and fro transition and for push u need navigation controller. the other transitions like coververtical, pagecurl, crossdissolve and fliphorizontal are provided by modal transition(without navigation controller) which we write as

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and i got a small doubt here y r u writing

```
 animated:NO
```

change it to

```
animated:YES
```

maybe it will solve the problem. try it once.

Happy coding

Comment: thanks for your answer sree.But that also not worked:-(

Comment: just keep the completion:NULL and try once

Comment: sorry @MaheThiru i have told all i known, u better try presentviewcontroller or **use custom presentation** of view and do ur required transition.

Comment: k no probs sree thanks for your valuable help..Then now i saw one thing that is the question i posted above with another method when i give timing is not more than 0 sec means in next viewcontroller the navigationcontroller is working if i give more than 0 means it is not working..Can u check with that code???

Comment: den sree the thing i need flip,curl,top to botttom,and bottom to animation for this..Is is possible to achieve all those animation with presentviewcontroller???

Comment: yes it is possible to do all the transitions with present or modal transition and no need of navigation controller for this transitions